# DPWS explorer is not starting in Snow Leopard

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, osx-snow-leopard

I am using Mac OsX 10.6.6. I had downloaded ws4d-explorer-v3.1-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.jar.

The when i run the DPWS explore from command prompt it hangs with following error.

> [INFO ] Problems occured when loading ./persistence/ExplorerProperties.xml    (java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/hba/Downloads/./persistence/ExplorerProperties.xml   (No such file or directory)).
>   [INFO ] Supported DPWS Version(s): DPWS1.1
>   [INFO ] DPWS Framework ready.
>   [INFO ] Explorer DPWS Version settings: DPWS2006 (disabled) & DPWS1.1 (enabeld)
>   2011-02-03 16:57:15.765 java[2557:c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x102413f70 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
>   2011-02-03 16:57:15.768 java[2557:c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10010d4f0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>   2011-02-03 16:57:15.769 java[2557:c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x102306b80 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
>   2011-02-03 16:57:15.779 java[2557:c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1024189e0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>   2011-02-03 16:57:15.780 java[2557:c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x102418ba0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>
>   2011-02-03 16:57:15.781 java[2557:c07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7fff706aafb0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   [INFO ] The DPWS Client of the DPWSExplorer is starting... Please wait!

Please let me know did some one has faced this issue. And how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured the problem. Please use the following command while running dpws explore in mac snow lepord

> > java -jar -d64 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -XstartOnFirstThread ws4d-explorer-v3.1-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.jar

it will work fine i belive there is a issue to run the DPWS stack with ipv6 so i forced it to work on ipv4